# Instantiate constructor with Class pointer as a parameter

Tags: c++

`a.hpp` file:

```
namespace hello  
{  
class A : public hi::B    
public:
    A(C* my_hello);    
private:    
    const C* p_hello; 
};
```

`a.cpp`:

```
hello::A::A(C* my_hello)    
: m_name(0);    
{  
}
```

In `b.cpp` file:

```
hello::A *random = new hello::A();
```

//-> Error in this line saying no instance of constructor
How to instantiate the constructor when there is a pointer to a class in the parameter

Comment: Yes, because your only constructor takes one parameter - you don't have a parameterless constructor

Comment: @UnholySheep if I do something like , new hello::A(C*) then also it does not work. Could you suggest me what I need to do?

Comment: Indent with four spaces to format code, or select and hit the `{}` button.

Comment: Don't say "does not work", it's not helpful. Say *what it does* or *what errors you get*.

Comment: This constructor has a *mandatory* argument, so unless you create a constructor variant with no arguments, or assign a default like `= nullptr` to this one, this code will not compile. It is invalid.

Comment: @tadman yes I formatted it now.

Comment: adding nullptr in the argument worked . Thanks @tadman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .hpp file, you aren't defining a constructor for A, you typed `hello(...)` instead.

Also, since you defined a constructor, your class doesn't have a default constructor anymore (i.e. one that doesn't need any arguments).

When calling the constructor of your class in the new expression, you must supply al needed arguments.